# NullPointerException with Firebase Authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm doing a blog app, but when I run it, I have this code of crash:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fgvelectro.f/com.fgvelectro.f.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference

I've searched on the net for days, without success. I've saw other threads that talked about that problem, but nothing solved. Here it is my MainActivity:

```
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mBlogList;

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseUsers;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

             if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){


                 Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                 loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                 startActivity(loginIntent);

             }

            }
        };

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");
        mDatabaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        mDatabaseUsers.keepSynced(true);

        mDatabase.keepSynced(true);

        mBlogList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.blog_list);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

        mBlogList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mBlogList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        checkUserExist();

        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);


        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(
                Blog.class,
                R.layout.blog_row,
                BlogViewHolder.class,
                mDatabase


        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog model, int position) {

                viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
                viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage());

            }
        };

        mBlogList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }

    private void checkUserExist() {

        final String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        mDatabaseUsers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if(!dataSnapshot.hasChild(user_id)){

                    Intent setupIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SetupActivity.class);
                    setupIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(setupIntent);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        View mView;

        public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title){

            TextView post_title = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
            post_title.setText(title);
        }

        public void setDesc(String desc){

            TextView post_desc = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
            post_desc.setText(desc);

        }

        public void setImage(Context ctx, String image){

            ImageView post_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_image);
        }

    }


    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_add){

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PostActivity.class));

        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_logout){

            logout();

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void logout() {

        mAuth.signOut();

    }
}
```

I know that is hard (and timewasting) to solve this problem, but if you can help me, thanks, thanks, thanks.

faby

---

Now my code looks like this:

```
private void checkUserExist() {

        final String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        mDatabaseUsers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if(!dataSnapshot.hasChild(user_id)){

                    Intent setupIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SetupActivity.class);
                    setupIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(setupIntent);

                }
                if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(loginIntent);
                }
                else{
                    String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                }
            }
```

what should I do? Is it ok?

[new edit]

Hi thanks but nothing worked. Firebase support is helping me now, I'll get you know if something will work

Comment: It's likely that *mAuth.getCurrentUser()* is nil which is why getUid() is throwing an error. Your Firebase is probably not initialized correctly and/or user is not authenticated. Some basic troubleshooting and stepping through the code will probably reveal the cause.

Answer (score 2):

In your app build.gradle, add this to your dependencies

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
```

and in java file;

```
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;


if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
//Go to login 
}
else{
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
 }
```

Comment: Where have I to put this code in java?

Comment: Add this code where u have to add uid in your code....

Comment: nothing, it doesn't work....

Comment: You probably want to put `checkUserExist()` into that else block (and remove it from `onStart` where it currently is).